# Encrypt / Decrypt a 10 digit number

Tags: encryption

I'm new to data encryption, and currently researching on encrypting a 10 digit number with (16bit / 32bit) encryption method. The constraint that i have is that the encrypted value can be a-z A-Z 0-9 and the lenght should be <=10

Would be of help if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Your question is too open ended. Which encryption method do you want to use? The only 'encryption' method that I can think of (of the top of my head, admittedly) that will DECREASE the length of the result would be to encode it into a base higher than 10, but that would be incredibly easy for anyone to do or reverse.

Comment: I'm open to any encryption method. I tried XOR, but the encryption value seems to duplicate for two different numbers. Will it be wise to device our own encryption algorithm? sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: XOR is a boolean operation, you might want to brush up on exactly what comprises an encryption method. What purpose are you using encryption for?

Comment: Apologies for being vague. The purpose is to send email to clients with URLs having parameter of ids in encrypted form (and hard to reverse if it falls in wrong hands) and decrypt them back to know who clicked on the link. I think i need to learn the basics of encryption before i proceed with this research. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Vigenere cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) in combination with dec2hex function on programming language you are using to encode the ids safely.

For example, if you use the keyword (in our case not a word, but a digits string), `12345`, then an example id of `5125891923` would become `6359303268`*. Then you can dec2hex it to get `17B0B4464` or you can also convert it to the base of 36 (0-9a-z) and get `2x65xt0`.

* In short, you append first digit of keyword to first digit of the id, then second digit of keyword to second digit of the id, ... first digit of keyword to sixth digit of the id, etc.

Comment: It is safe if you don't have big enough source to calculate the keyword. And here is exactly the case. Plus, there's absolutely no way to figure that it was used. After converting base back to 10 attacker will recieve a number. There's no letter frequency or anything, no way to crack.

Comment: What I mean is a number doesn't give any information. If there's a word and you know it's english and then you see letters which don't make any sense, then you know it's crypted. When you see number you simply don't know, because there's no way to figure if it's a valid id or crypted id. Same way you can't decrypt it unless you find a way to validate it - any number will be just a number.

Comment: **The Vigenere cipher is a classical cipher; it is not secure**. The only way to make it secure is if the key is completely random, never reused (in which case it resembles an OTP). This would have been a good answer in the 15th century.